# how to call a page on a jsf button click

Tags: jsf

I'm using JSF, trying a to call a page on a button click inside a data table using the following code

```
 <h:column>
    <h:outputText value=""/>
    <h:commandButton id = "btn" value="History" action="#{Bean.showHistory}">
    </h:commandButton>
 </h:column>
```

My bean class icludes a method "showHistory" which returns success and I've included the navigation rule in faces-config.xml too but still the page couldn't be called. My navigation rule looks

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>Bean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>
        com.bean.HistoryBean
    </managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
<navigation-rule>
    <display-name>List</display-name>
    <from-view-id>/BookList.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/History.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Bean Class consists of showHistory() as

```
public String showHistory() {
    return "success";
}
```

Can I get a help to resolve this????

Comment: Is your method called at all (Letter "B" should be lowercase, a typo?). How does your navigation rule look like?

Comment: I've included my navigation rule in my post..in the BookList.jsp the button History in placed, when clicked should open History.jsp.U can also find the managed bean, where HistoryBean class consists of method showHistory() which returns success.

Comment: Do you have another action method in your bean that returns "succes"? If so, you should add the `<from-action>#{bean.showHistory}</from-action>` to your navigation case.

Comment: Sorryy..Couldn't get you.I dont have any other action method in this bean which returns "success", but do have a similar action method in a different bean

Comment: Could you add the showHistory method?

Comment: sorry I'm unable to understand. where should showHistory() be added, if its in the faces-config.xml, can u please be more clear.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say, that you add the source code of the method to your question.

Comment: Debug and verify that your showHistory() method is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you put the command button inside a `h:form` element: it should work!

Answer (score 0):

From your source code everything looks good (of course including Pier's suggestion to use the `h:form` tag).

Try to debug and check if your action method is called at all.

If not, then maybe your `from-view-id` element does not match. As a test you could try it with an empty element (default navigation for all pages):

```
<from-view-id></from-view-id>
```

If this works, then the problem is with your `from-view-id` element. Maybe it's in a different folder or an upper/lower case typo.

Comment: thanks for ur time Handy.I tried debugging it couldn't call the method as u said,but acc to Pier's suggestion it worked fine